# Using python unittest with monkeyrunner vs without monkeyrunner

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, unit-testing, monkeyrunner

I have this:

```
import unittest
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):

        @classmethod    
        def setUpClass(cls):
            cls.g = "def"
            print cls

        def test_upper(self):
            self.assertEqual('DeF'.lower(), TestStringMethods.g)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This

`python test.py`

gives:

```
python screen_test.py
<class '__main__.TestStringMethods'>
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

But, this:

```
monkeyrunner "%CD%\test.py"
```

gives:

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_upper (__main__.TestStringMethods)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abc\def\ghi\jkl\test.py", line 29, in test_upper
    self.assertEqual('DeF'.lower(), TestStringMethods.g)
AttributeError: type object 'TestStringMethods' has no attribute 'g'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.024s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Why is the same test failing when run with monkeyrunner ?

Also where is that lone `E` coming from?

Answer (score 1):

As you may have discovered already, this is because `monkeyrunner` is not running the `setUpClass` method.

You can use [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) as a drop-in replacement for `monkeyrunner` with the advantage that it runs with python 2.x, so your tests will be correctly initialized.

Furthermore, `culebra -U` could generate tests automatically, which you can then customize.

This is a snippet from a generated test (with some lines removed for clarity):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# ...    
import unittest

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient, CulebraTestCase

TAG = 'CULEBRA'


class CulebraTests(CulebraTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        # ...
        cls.sleep = 5

    def setUp(self):
        super(CulebraTests, self).setUp()

    def tearDown(self):
        super(CulebraTests, self).tearDown()

    def preconditions(self):
        if not super(CulebraTests, self).preconditions():
            return False
        return True

    def testSomething(self):
        if not self.preconditions():
            self.fail('Preconditions failed')

        _s = CulebraTests.sleep
        _v = CulebraTests.verbose

        ## your test code here ##



if __name__ == '__main__':
    CulebraTests.main()
```

`CulebraTestCase` provides the heavy lifting, connecting the test with `adb` and the available devices, processing the command line options, etc.

Comment: But why is monkeyrunner not calling the setUpClass() method ?

Comment: Perhaps is ignoring the decorators